# Confusing sentence using "eher"

Tags: meaning, usage

I was trying to see how "eher" is used by looking on dict.cc, and I came upon a sentence I don't completely understand. Can someone tell me what each of the words "sonst", "eher", and "selten" contributes to the meaning of the following sentence?

..., die alle sonst eher selten einer Meinung wären.

(... all of whom would otherwise rarely be of the same opinion.)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

"Eher selten" translates to "*rather* rarely", here.

*Eher* has basically the meaning of:

- "earlier" (temporal)
- "rather", "more probable",
- and can also act as a sort of *auxiliary comparative* as in "eher selten"